# GroupHeaderTemplate has extra height in Xamarin.Forms iOS project

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with GroupHeaderTemplate on iOS (Xamarin.Forms). It works perfect on Android, but on iPhone the height of group header is much higher than actually needed.

One picture is worth a thousand words. Take a look at green areas - those are group headers. As you can see each of them has an extra space over.
[image: Failing iOS group headers]

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the following code , add the CustomRenderer in your iOS project .

```
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using XXX;
using XXX.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView),typeof(MyListViewRenderer))]
namespace XXX.iOS
{
    public class MyListViewRenderer:ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(new UITableView(Control.Frame, UITableViewStyle.Plain) { Source = Control.Source });
            }
        }
    }
}
```